# How can I write two For Loops when I do webscraping with Python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, web-scraping

I want to write a code to scrape multiple webpages.

However, the problem is that there are two numbers variations in the webpage.

```
000/BBSDD0002/93976?page=1&
000/BBSDD0002/93975?page=1&
000/BBSDD0002/93970?page=1&
000/BBSDD0002/93964?page=1&
000/BBSDD0002/93950?page=1&
000/BBSDD0002/93946?page=1&
000/BBSDD0002/93945?page=1&
000/BBSDD0002/93930?page=2&
000/BBSDD0002/93925?page=2&
.
.
.
.
000/BBSDD0002/39045?page=536&
```

As we see here, both pagenumber and document number are varying at the same time.

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import product

page = range(1, 6)
document = range(39045, 93976)



for i, j in product(page, document):
    print("Page Number:", i)
    url = "https://000.com/BBSDD0002/{}?page={}&".format(i,j)
    res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    res.raise_for_status()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    
    list1=soup.find_all("td", attrs = {"class":"sbj"})
    for li in list1:
        print(li.get_text())
```

I wrote it this so far, but it only loops the page numbers, so it does not give me anything.

Are there any ways to create a look for both page numbers and document numbers?

Comment: have you just indented wrong or have you copied code into question incorrectly? Also your document number should be looped before your page number. You get a document first then flip through the pages

Comment: Hi, I just edited the code. Please take a look!

Comment: don't know what product is in your first line (your code is incomplete) but if it returns a page/document pairs in that order, your url string should be formatted with `.format(j,i)` not `.format(i,j)`

Comment: Ooops, I just added the first a few lines. Basically, there are 536 pages in the webpages, and 39045~93976 numbers should be added in the URL loop.

Comment: Again, inspect the url after you create it. You need to reverse the i and j in your format statement so you get the correct url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your goal is with this, but you could do it that way:

```
page = range(1, 6)
entry_id = 39045

for p in page:
    for i in range(0,10):
        print(f'https://000.com/BBSDD0002/{entry_id}?page={p}')
        entry_id = entry_id+1
```

What leads to:

```
https://000.com/BBSDD0002/39045?page=1
https://000.com/BBSDD0002/39046?page=1
https://000.com/BBSDD0002/39047?page=1
https://000.com/BBSDD0002/39048?page=1
https://000.com/BBSDD0002/39049?page=1
https://000.com/BBSDD0002/39050?page=1
https://000.com/BBSDD0002/39051?page=1
https://000.com/BBSDD0002/39052?page=1
https://000.com/BBSDD0002/39053?page=1
https://000.com/BBSDD0002/39054?page=1
https://000.com/BBSDD0002/39055?page=2
https://000.com/BBSDD0002/39056?page=2
https://000.com/BBSDD0002/39057?page=2
https://000.com/BBSDD0002/39058?page=2
https://000.com/BBSDD0002/39059?page=2
https://000.com/BBSDD0002/39060?page=2
https://000.com/BBSDD0002/39061?page=2
https://000.com/BBSDD0002/39062?page=2
https://000.com/BBSDD0002/39063?page=2
https://000.com/BBSDD0002/39064?page=2
https://000.com/BBSDD0002/39065?page=3
https://000.com/BBSDD0002/39066?page=3
https://000.com/BBSDD0002/39067?page=3
...
```

*If you try to scrape the comments - Why not iterating the pages and collect their urls. This will also prevent you from creating invalid urls for removed comments in example.*